# Java inline method/strategy for truncating String?

Tags: java, string, substring, apache-commons

If I have a String:

`String neatish = getTheString(); // returns "...neat..."`

I know that I can get rid of the first ellipsis using:

`getTheString().substring(3);`

But I'm wondering if there's a similar one-line method that takes the *end* off, based on **length**? Like:

`getTheString().substring(3).truncate(3);`

I don't want a character-specific method, ie. one that works only on ellipses.

While there's a `substring()` that accepts two parameters, it requires the altering `String` to be saved off to a variable first to determine the length. (Or, you can call `getTheString()` twice.)

I can certainly write one, but I'm wondering if there is a one-line method **either in** the standard `java.lang` package, or in Apache Commons-Lang, that will accomplish this.

I'm 50% curious, and 50% avoiding re-inventing the wheel.

**Update:** To avoid confusion, I do not want:

```
String neatish = getTheString();
neatish = neatish.substring(3)...;
```

I'm instead looking for the back-end version of `substring()`, and wondering why there isn't one.

Comment: the length of `"somestring".substring(3)` is usually `"somestring".length() - 3`

Comment: Am I missing something or don't you just need `neatish = neatish.replaceAll("\\.\\.\\.", "");` ?

Comment: @BrianRoach I don't want an ellipsis-specific pattern, just a general method based on a length.

Comment: @John Huh? You can chain as many methods as you want.

Comment: @CraigOtis I understand now. Was taking it too literally.

Comment: @BrianRoach What are you talking about? `"someString".charAt(0).substring(0,3)` absolutely does not work. The very moment you put that dot on the literal, you lose the literal and get a `char` instead. You can only dot the literal ONCE. I wish I hadn't deleted my comment before you responded. Java's `String` class absolutely does not support method cascading.

Comment: @CraigOtis So ... I may still be being dense, but wouldn't the two-arg version of `substring()` do what you want?

Comment: @BrianRoach What do you propose the second parameter of his two arg substring be if the location of the ellipsis is unknown?

Comment: Indeed a String.removeFromTail(int n) is missing in String.

Comment: @AlexWien And also seemingly missing from Apache Commons `StringUtils`, hence my confusion.

Comment: Objective-C String class is more powerfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [subStringBefore and subStringAfter from Commons](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringBefore%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

```
StringUtils.subStringAfter(StringUtils.subStringBefore(getTheString(), "..."), "...");
```

EDIT **based on length**:

You need: [StringUtils.html#substring(java.lang.String, int, int)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29)

```
StringUtils.substring(getTheString(), 3, -3);
```

Comment: Not looking for an ellipsis-specific method though - just one based on length.

Comment: Your updated answer with the negative third parameter is the best so far. I didn't realize that the `StringUtils` version of `substring()` accepted negative arguments.

Comment: Apache Commons has eeeeverything ;)

Answer (score 2):

Fun exercise

```
String theString = new StringBuilder(getTheString()).delete(0, 3).reverse().delete(0, 3).reverse().toString();
```

Get the `String` into a [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), remove the first 3 chars, reverse it, remove the last 3 chars (which are now at the start), reverse it again.

Comment: I think K.C. has you beat. :) But this is a pretty creative answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
getTheString().substring(3).replaceFirst("(?s)...$", "");
getTheString().replaceFirst("(?s)^...(.*)...$", "$1");
```

This removes the last 3 chars by a regular expression, where `(?s)` make `.` also match newlines. Use `\\.` to match a period. UGLY.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a method to do it.

```
public static String trimChar(String s, char ch) {
    int start = 0;
    for(; start < s.length(); start++)
         if (s.charAt(start) != ch)
             break;
    int end = s.length();
    for(; end > start; end--)
         if (s.charAt(end-1) != ch)
             break;
    return s.substring(start, end);
}


String s = trimChar(getTheString(), '.');
```